# NetBeans performance severely degrades with many bower and npm dependencies

Tags: performance, netbeans

I'm using what is currently the latest version of NetBeans (~8.0.0) to develop a MEAN (**M**ongo, **E**xpress, **A**ngular, **N**ode) application. Since this is relatively large project, my `bower_components` and `node_modules` directories have grown quite a bit and it seems like NetBeans is constantly trying to scan them in the background, causing very high CPU and memory usage and eventually the UI becomes very sluggish.

This is on a high-end laptop with a Core i7, 8GB of memory and a SSD so hardware isn't the issue here.

I've set this up as a HTML5 project so it is not possible to set ignored folders since, for some reason, this feature is restricted to PHP projects.

Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, although it isn't perfect, there is a workaround to this problem.

`Tools` > `Options` > `Miscellaneous` > `Files` > `Ignored Files Patterns`

By default the pattern is set to:

`^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$`

Change this to the following:

`^(bower_components|node_modules|CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$`

This will prevent NetBeans from constantly scanning `bower_components` and `node_modules`. The downside is that they will no longer appear in the directory list.